# How to get started with ARM STM32 and GUI on TFT display

Tags: user-interface, arm, embedded, stm32

I just bought myself these :

- [STM32 ARM Cortex-M3 STM32F107VCT6 Development Board + 3.2" TFT LCD](http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/181489822540)
- [ULINK2 USB JTAG Emulator support MDK4.54 ARM7 Cortex Keil Debug Adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/221589874455)

I want to do a simple HelloWorld Gui app, let's say that shows a Button and once I click it, it turns on a led.

I have some experience in AVR / Arduino development, but none with ARM

Where should I start ? Is there a library for Windows-like controls ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should get started with the examples on the linked CD - you never know, someone else might have already created an example for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have some examples on the CD, they are most in chinese.... Any suggestion on the IDE to use with that programmer/debugger I have ?

Comment: Any suggestions of a good sauce to eat with my dinner? Any suggestions of the right colour tie to match this shirt I am wearing? As you don't say what programmer/debugger you have, it is completely impossible for me to comment.

Comment: There is no ARM STM32. And the STM32 family has 4 (5 if we count M0 and M0+ as two) different cores.

Answer (score 0):

It is a ILI9325 based display board if I am correct. Searching for libraries and example code on the internet would yield lots of results.

Examples I found:
  - [Similar Adafriut product](https://learn.adafruit.com/2-8-tft-touch-shield)
  - [Libstock ILI9325 TFT Touch Screen Display Demo with STM32](http://libstock.mikroe.com/projects/view/1797/ili9325-tft-touch-screen-display-demo-with-stm32)
  - [stm32plus 2.0.0 the driver for STM32 F4](http://andybrown.me.uk/2012/01/01/stm32plus-ili9325-tft-driver/)

Answer (score -2):

I do not know how many memory does it have, nor which processor, but maybe you could consider QT (https://www.qt.io/qt-for-device-creation/)

Comment: "I do not know how many memory does it have, nor which processor" - So you don't know what the question is about, but post a comment as answer with a toolkit which does not even support that platform. (Hint: a simple search for STM32` should show at least which CPU cores would be available.) Let alone that off-topic questions should not be answered anyway.